# Reset Wordpress Post Query to default

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, query-posts, get-posts, recent-posts

i am in a situation,
i am creating a custom wordpress theme but i am stuck over something.

in my index/home page, firstly i am displaying 6 posts by category like below

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=2&numberposts=6'); foreach($posts as $post) {
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Now After displaying 6 post successfully by category, i want to display the most recent posts using the main post loop using code below.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
     _e('<p class="nopost">Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>');
endif;?>
```

**The Problem:**

My home page is showing 6 post by category very well with no errors but in recent posts section of my home page, instead of showing recent posts the section is showing up the same post as there were in above category post.

i guess there must be a way to reset the query after displaying the category post. 
Please help me out.

Comment: Also when i am removing the get post by category code, the recent posts are appearing as i wanted

Comment: Do not use `$posts`, rather use another variable like `$posts_query`, and add `wp_reset_postdata();` after your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Also, after this line, `foreach($posts as $post) {`, add `setup_postdata( $post )` in order to make the use of template tags available

Comment: you made my day, thanks for saving my time. @pieter goosen

Comment: @pietergoosen : why did you post a comment instead of a proper answer?

Comment: Any reason why you did not accept my answer. By not accepting my answer, it means the question is still unsolved. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your custom query. Do not use variables that is used by default by Wordpress. `$posts` and `$post` is Wordpress reserved global variables. Change `$post` to a unique variable, something like `$posts_query`.

When using `get_posts` and you need to setup postdata to make use of template tags, you have no choiche but to use `$post` as `setup_postdata()` needs `$post` to be passed to it. This breaks the main query `$post` global, so you need to reset that once done. This is done with `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Just a note on your code, template tags are not available by default when usng `get_posts`, so you need to add `setup_postdata( $post );` inside your `foreach` loop to make the use of template tags available

Your custom query should look something like this

```
$posts_query = get_posts( 'YOUR ARGUMENTS' );
if ( $posts_query ) {
    foreach ( $posts_query as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); 

        // You can now use template tags like the_title() and the_content()

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```